# How to insert the values of mathematical expression into a Column in R

Tags: r

I have a dataset with the following 4 column types, see the struct of the data frame below

```
>str(df)
 >data.frame':  108517 obs. of  4 variables:
 >$ CustomerID: int  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
 >$ Activity: chr  " 418 " " 2 " " 1,868 " " 6,319 " ...
 >$ Country : chr  "Germany" "Germany" "England" "Belgium" ...
 >$ Customer_Group   : int  1 4 3 5 5 5 2 1 1 3 ...
```

I want to create a fifth column, and fill the column up with "Total Sales" from each customer,

(Total_Sales is normally calculated by multiplying customer activity with 0.511 and minus discount level based on customer's group)

My code is below

```
>Activity <- as.integer(gsub(",", "", df$Activity))
>attach(df)
>df$Total_Sales[df$Customer_Group == 1] <- ((0.511 * Activity) - 50)
>df$Total_Sales[df$Customer_Group == 2] <- ((0.511 * Activity) - 65)
>df$Total_Sales[df$Customer_Group == 3] <- ((0.511 * Activity) - 20)
>df$Total_Sales[df$Customer_Group == 4] <- ((0.511 * Activity) - 35)
>df$Total_Sales[df$Customer_Group == 5] <- ((0.511 * Activity) - 0)
>detach(df)
```

1. I get this error by attaching the dataset

   > The following object is masked *by* .GlobalEnv:
   >   Activity
   >   The following objects are masked from df (pos = 3):
   >   Activity, Country, Customer_Group, CustomerID
2. Also when I continued, I get the following errors that "number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length"

When I manually checked my newly created column, Total_Sales, the majority of the values are not correct (NOT the desired result). What are my doing wrong, please? I need your help.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you need to `attach`? Your code doesn't seem to need it. To see your problem, change your first line to `0.511 * Activity[df$Customer_Group == 1] - 50`

Comment: I really do discourage the use of `attach`; not because it doesn't work (it does), but because many mistakes or poor techniques can be masked while `attach`ed, and some other problems are either unclear or very difficult to troubleshoot. Especially since (as sebastian-c identified) you appear to be not using it, just don't `attach`/`detach`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. This is not an error, but a warning letting you know what `attach` is doing. You've specified Activity as an independent vector, but it is also a column in the dataframe you're attaching. When you attach a dataframe, R has to pick between the vector you've just created and the column, because they both have the same name now.
2. This error occurs because you are not comparing vectors of equal length. On the left side of these lines, you have a subset of the rows of your dataframe. On the right side, however, you're just transforming the entirety of the Activity vector. These aren't of equal length, so R doesn't know what to do with them.

If you remove the `attach()` and `detach()` lines and change the code to rows like this, your script will run fine:

```
df$Total_Sales[df$Customer_Group == 1] <- ((0.511 * as.numeric(gsub(",", "", df$Activity)[df$Customer_Group == 1])) - 50)
```

Comment: Thank you, guys.  it worked. df$Total_Sales[df$Customer_Group == 1] <- ((0.511 * as.numeric(gsub(",", "", df$Activity)[df$Customer_Group == 1])) - 50)

Comment: Of course, I'd forgotten about the transformation to numeric data type. I've changed the answer to include it.